# If $X \sim N_{p}(0,\Sigma)$ is independent of $Y \sim N(0,1)$, what is the characteristic function of $\frac{X}{Y}$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Suppose that I have that $X \sim N_{p}(0,\Sigma)$ and that $Y \sim N(0,1)$ is **independent** of $X$. Let $Z = \frac{X}{Y}$, I would like to find the characteristic function of $Z$:

$$
\phi_Z(z) = E[e^{itZ}]
$$

To do this, I use the conditional iterated expectations formula:

$$
\begin{align}
\phi_Z(z) &= E[e^{itZ}] \\
&= E\left[e^{itX/Y}\right] \\
&= E\left[E\left[e^{itX/Y}|Y\right]\right]\\
&= E\left[\exp\left(-{\frac{1}{2Y^2}t^T\Sigma t}\right)\right]
\end{align}
$$

since the characteristic equation for a multivariate normal $X$ with zero mean is $E(e^{itX}) = e^{-\frac{1}{2}t^T\Sigma t}$.

However, from this point forward I am not sure what to do, does anyone have any ideas? thanks.

Comment: I suppose you mean $E\left[\exp\left(\dfrac{-1}{2Y^2} t^T \Sigma t\right)\right]$.

Comment: Yes, thank you for pointing it out, changed it!

Comment: Don't forget the $-$.  It would diverge without that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $s = t^T \Sigma t$.

$$\mathbb E \left[ \exp\left(-\dfrac{s}{2Y^2}\right)\right] = \dfrac{\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{\pi}} \int_0^\infty \exp\left(-(y^2+s/y^2)/2\right)\; dy = \exp(-\sqrt{s})$$

Comment: Thanks! Would you know if there is a way to do the expectation by recognizing it as the moment generating function or the characteristic function of a distribution?